# Folder specifics sharing permissions SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, item-level-permissions

I have a site/teams and external sharing is enable top level. however I want to disable external sharing in a few of the folders within this.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No. The sharing options are applied to the whole site. If you need different permissions to some of the site's content, I suggest you move that content to a different site with adequate permissions. It's only a link away.

Comment: is it possible to control this by security group?

Comment: Is WHAT possible to control by security group? Security groups control WHO can access the site for READ or EDIT. Security groups do not control how content can be shared.